# Setting a global Scripting.Dictionary in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have a function that is appending a dictionary. I want to keep the contents of this dictionary as long as the `updateList` isn't true. I currently have it setup like this:

```
Public Function runPolluxFull(voerUit As Boolean, updateList As Boolean)

Dim dicTitle As Variable
Dim dicFound As Variable

If updateList = True Then
Set dicTitle = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dicFound = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

While status
        Set ObjectsJSON = jsonlibPollux.parse(responseString)

        With dicTitle
        .Add inc, ObjectsJSON.Item("title")
        End With

        With dicFound
        .Add inc, ObjectsJSON.Item("description")
        End With

Wend
End If
```

And when `voerUit` is true the following happens:

```
For i = 1 To dicTitle.Count
klaar = findReplace(dicTitle.Item(i), "x" + dicTitle.Item(i), dicTitle.Item(i) + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + dicFound.Item(i))
Next i
```

The problem here is that when this function ends, `dicTitle` and `dicFound` are cleared, and the `findReplace` function gets fed empty arguments.

Is there anyway to makes to code work, or a good workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime to use binding like I have used. It is preferable to the manner you are declaring them as you have better access to the object and can see member variables easier, etc.

### Method 1 - module level or public variables for dictionaries

One way you can do this is to create module level variables for the scripting dictionaries you are using:

```
Public gDicTitle As Scripting.Dictionary
Public gDicFound As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function runPolluxFull(voerUit As Boolean, updateList As Boolean)


    If updateList = True Then
        Set gDicTitle = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Set gDicFound = New Scripting.Dictionary
        
        While Status
                Set ObjectsJSON = jsonlibPollux.Parse(responseString)
        
                With gDicTitle
                .Add inc, ObjectsJSON.Item("title")
                End With
        
                With gDicFound
                .Add inc, ObjectsJSON.Item("description")
                End With
    
        Wend
    End If
End Function
```

### Method 2 - static references to dictionaries

You can also do this by making the dictionaries [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733578(v=vs.60).aspx). This will preserve them between function calls like the documentation says.

```
Public Function runPolluxFull(voerUit As Boolean, updateList As Boolean)
    Static gDicTitle As Scripting.Dictionary
    Static gDicFound As Scripting.Dictionary
    
    If updateList = True Then
        Set gDicTitle = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Set gDicFound = New Scripting.Dictionary
        
        While Status
                Set ObjectsJSON = jsonlibPollux.Parse(responseString)
        
                With gDicTitle
                .Add inc, ObjectsJSON.Item("title")
                End With
        
                With gDicFound
                .Add inc, ObjectsJSON.Item("description")
                End With
    
        Wend
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Whne I set dicTitle with `Scripting.Dictionary` (static, or without), I get a compiling error saying that the type is not defined (sorry have a Dutch install, so I have to translate error message's).

Comment: @MartijnNosyncerror - You have to add a reference to that library in your VBA editor, add what in English is the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. I added that to the top of my answer.

Comment: That did the trick for that error, problem is that my dictionary is still empty when using it in the `findReplace` function. I checked, and both dictionaries get populated with the first snippit, but still end up being deleted when that `While` loop ends..

Comment: @MartijnNosyncerror please post the rest of your code for the function exactly as you are using it with your problem, it seems you must have more code in your runPollufFull function than what I used here.

Comment: Yes I have but it's a lot of junk that isn't really relevant to the problem. I will post it on pastebin because of the size, but it's mostly in Dutch (and bad programming, which is the worst part :D) http://pastebin.com/a47vtBv8

Comment: Thanks for the help and the fast replies, been banging my head on this for 3 days now. First time doing something with VBA

Comment: After messing around with it, it apeared my error was comming from antoher bug. The second answer worked for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have tried both and i havent had any succes yet
(I also got mine in dutch but i can change it to english)
I get the error `Compile Error: User-defined type not defined` do you have any tips?