# VBA: using a dictionary outside of a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba so I might have missed something.

I am filling a dictionary `DicOption` in a sub from a Module.
This is the sub:

```
Public Sub ExchangeToDicOption()

Static DicOption As Object
Dim LR As Long
Dim Rg As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Set Rg = ws.Columns(2)

If Not DicOption Is Nothing Then
    DicOption.RemoveAll
End If


    LR = Rg.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    Set DicOption = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If LR > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To LR
            DicOption.Add key:=Cells(i, 1).Value, Item:=Cells(i, 2).Value
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

But the dictionary seems to empty itself when it finishes its process.I am calling the sub `ExchangeToDicOption` in UserForm_Initialize. Creation_step is a key in `DicOption`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim control As control
Dim opt As String

Call ExchangeToDicOption

opt = DicOption(Creation_step)
With UBidStatus
    Select Case opt
        Case Is > 0
            For Each control In UBidStatus.Controls
                control.Enabled = False
            Next control
            With UBidStatus
                .Image4.Enabled = True
                .LProject.Enabled = True
                .LClient.Enabled = True
                .Label6.Enabled = True
                .Label7.Enabled = True
                .IProjectinfoNOK.Enabled = True
                .IProjectinfoOK.Enabled = True
                .LProjectinfo.Enabled = True
                .CBProjectinfo.Enabled = True
                .IProjectinfoNOK.Visible = True
                .IProjectinfoOK.Visible = False
            End With
ect....
```

I also tried to use `Public DicOption as Object` as a global variable (before all my subs in Module edit window) but it didn't work either.
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I had previously refer to this thread to help me complete my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382729/setting-a-global-scripting-dictionary-in-visual-basic-for-applications-vba

Comment: You should probably remove the Goto Fill, Else and Fill label...and move the End If up to where you have the Else.  It's bad form to have one part of your If Goto the other part.  Just doesn't make sense logically.  That won't solve your issue, just isn't good programming.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Rdster, I also thought it was weird but I guess I was focusing more on the dictionary problem. I will take your advice and change that  code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub ExchangeToDicOption()

Static DicOption As Object
```

The `DicOption` object variable is in *local scope* - it only ever exists inside the `ExchangeToDicOption` procedure.

This line in `UserForm_Initialize`:

```
opt = DicOption(Creation_step)
```

Looks like it's trying to access a variable declared in another scope. **It can't.**

Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules; that form stops compiling. Or, **if** there's another `DicOption` variable in module-scope (declared at the top of the module, above the procedures), then the `DicOption` that's local to `ExchangeToDicOption` is *hiding* it (VBA resolves calls to `DicOption` to the local declaration, not the module-level one). Remove the `Static DicOption As Object` declaration.

Since you have two procedures that need to access the same object, you need to declare that object at module level.

```
Option Explicit
Private DicOption As Object

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set DicOption = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Set DicOption = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub ExchangeToDicOption()
    DicOption.RemoveAll
    LR = Rg.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    If LR > 1 Then
        For i = 2 To LR
            DicOption.Add key:=Cells(i, 1).Value, Item:=Cells(i, 2).Value
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, not sure why you're late-binding to a library that's standard-installed on any Windows box since 1998... but that's another issue.

By initializing the instance in `UserForm_Initialize` and killing it in `UserForm_Terminate`, you're ensuring to have a non-null object reference for the entire lifetime of the `UserForm` object instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mat's Mug, I have to admit that I need to learn more about object propertys and instance ans I will include your closing method to my code. As for the dictionary I was using late binding because i read that it was more robust for multi-user purpose

Comment: Late binding will load the last installed version of a given library, so if you early-bind to *SomeRandomLibrary v2.4* and a user has v2.6 installed, the binding will fail because early binding is version-specific. The scripting library hasn't had an update this century though, and isn't likely to get one either.

Comment: Also, shouldn't I make `Public DictOption As Object` instead of  `Private DicOption As Object` so it will be available for other forms/subs? Do I have to initializing and terminate in all form that uses DicOption? Or are you sugesting that intitialize and terminate goes in my general module and not my ''form'' module?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a personal vendetta against exposing public fields on objects; if it's `Public`, then anyone outside the module can just `Set frm.DicOptions = Nothing` and wreck everything. I'd expose a `Public Property Get GetOption(ByVal name As String) As String` that returns the dictionary value at the specified key. That way code outside the form simply cannot `Set` that reference in any way, and can still read every value from it.

Comment: @GabrielHébertMaheu `UserForm_Initialize` and `UserForm_Terminate` are handlers that can only exist in the form's code-behind.

Comment: That seems neat, but it works well with a public object for now. I will try to learn more on property soon, but I need to speed up with my work. I will check mark your answer  since the code you have posted is working. Hope it can help other users also. Thanks again!

Comment: Of course it works with a public field - the problem is that it's easy to later introduce bugs by accessing that field in a way it wasn't *meant* to be used, e.g. `Set frm.DicOptions = New Dictionary` or `Set frm.DicOptions = Nothing`, 6 months down the line, by future you, or by future maintainer; a read-only property makes that kind of misuse impossible, and conveys *intent* more explicitly - *that's* the difference! ;-)

Comment: @ Mat's Mug , I finally got time to learn about property and class module, (as userform are a class module from my understanding). I find it nice to have a `Public Property Get GetOption(ByVal name As String) As String` but I can't figure how to make a new entry in the dictionnary with the  `Property Let` since I need two value for that : the key and the item. I need to add several new key and item in other userform to this dictionary. Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: Your `Property Let` member can have as many parameters as you need. `Public Property Let SetOption(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)` - as long as the last parameter is the same type as the property itself. Such properties are called "indexed properties"

Comment: That is fine because i am using string for keys and item. How can i use this property then `Userform.GetOption = Cells(i, 10).Value`  + `Cells(i, 2).Value`??? (to add a new key/item to the dictionary)

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion - the property name must be the same for both `Let` and `Get` members, I'd call it `Options`. So you "get" with `foo = theForm.Options("key")` and you "let" with `theForm.Options("key") = foo`.

Comment: This is ok to enter a new item value. I am trying to figure out how to enter a new "key" with property but my brain is going in infinite loop ... (i need to check if key already exist to avoid error)

Comment: Implement the logic for that in the `Property Let` member, which *has* both the `key` and `value` parameters you need.